# ¿Como usar un SP en dapper?

Tags: c#, asp.net, dapper

Estoy intentando hacer una validación, lo que debe de hacer es regresarme un 1 o 0 si es que la relación entre Autores y Libros ya existe, estos datos se guardan en una tabla Relación lo único que se guarda en esta tabla es el ID de la tabla, el IdAutor que es foráneo, IdLibro que de igual forma es foráneo, y la fecha de creación, el problema es que no se como llamar al SP ni como recuperar el valor que me debería de retornar, adjunto mi SP y como es que yo hago las consultas de lo demás, Cabe aclarar que estoy usando Dapper.

````
CREATE PROC verificarInsertRelacion @idAutor INT, @idLibro INT
AS


IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 
           FROM Relaciones 
           WHERE idAutor = @idAutor AND idLibro = @idLibro ) 
BEGIN
 SELECT 1 Resultado 
END
ELSE BEGIN 
 SELECT 0 Resultado
END

EXEC verificarInsertRelacion 28,17```


public class RelacionesRepository : Repository
{
    private static IReadOnlyDictionary<string, string> _queries = new Dictionary<string, string>()
    {
        { "GetAllRelaciones", "SELECT * FROM RelacionLibroAutorSegunda_v" }

    };

    public RelacionesRepository(string connectionString, object? user) : base(connectionString, user) { }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<DbVwRelacionLibroAutor>> GetAllAsync()
    {
        IEnumerable<DbVwRelacionLibroAutor> relaciones;

        try
        {
            using IDbConnection connection = OpenConnection();

            relaciones = await connection
                .QueryAsync<DbVwRelacionLibroAutor>(_queries["GetAllRelaciones"]);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw;
        }

        return relaciones;

    }

    private void ValidateRequest(in RelacionesRequestDto request)
    {
        //Esto es lo que estoy intentando, pero al ser diferente como lo hago el resto no tengo mucha idea
        var parameters = "verificarInsertRelacion";
        using IDbConnection connection = OpenConnection();

        using (connection)
        {

            var query = connection.Query<RelacionesRequestDto>(parameters,
                new {IdAutor = 28, IdLibro = 16},
                commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
        }
            
            if (request.IdAutor == 28)
            {
                var exception = new ArgumentNullException(nameof(request),
                    "Este autor ya no se puede usar");

                throw exception;
            }

      
    }

    public async Task<ResponseEntry> InsertAsync(RelacionesRequestDto request)
    {
        #region Validaciones
        try
        {
            ValidateRequest(request);
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            return new ResponseEntry()
            {
                Success = false,
                Message = exception.Message,
                Title = "Validacion inicial"
            };
        }
        #endregion

        using IDbConnection connection = OpenConnection();

        DateTime timeStamp = DateTime.Now;

        DbTbRelaciones entry = new DbTbRelaciones()
        {
            IdAutor = request.IdAutor,
            IdLibro = request.IdLibro,
            CreationDate = timeStamp,
        };

        int identity = await connection.InsertAsync(entry);

        return new ResponseEntry()
        {
            Identity = identity,
            Success = true
        };
    }

    public async Task<ResponseEntry> UpdateAsync(RelacionesRequestDto request)
    {
        using IDbConnection connection = OpenConnection();

        RelacionesUpdateDto entry = new()
        {
            Id = request.Id,
            IdAutor = request.IdAutor,
            IdLibro = request.IdLibro
        };

        bool succes = await connection.UpdateAsync(entry);

        return new ResponseEntry()
        {
            Success = succes,
            Identity = request.Id
        };
    }
````

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo resolví es mas sencillo de lo que pensaba. Ya solo faltaría rellenar el catch y poner lo que se quiere hacer en el if.

````
private void ValidateRequest(in RelacionesRequestDto request)
    {
        using IDbConnection connection = OpenConnection();

        int result = 0;
        try
        {
            string query = "verificarInsertRelacion";
            var query_values = new
            {
                @idAutor = request.IdAutor,
                @idLibro = request.IdLibro
            };
            result = connection.Query<int>(query, query_values, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure).FirstOrDefault();
            if(result > 0)
            {

            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            
        }


    }```
````